# Java servlet is not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How can you map a *JSP* with a *servlet*? I created a login form in a *JSP* page and then send it throught `HttpPost` to a *servlet* so that I can validate it. However, I keep getting this error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
>   practicea.OnServletLogin

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class practicea.OnServletLogin
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: practicea.OnServletLogin
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Not sure why but here is my Home.jsp form:

```
<body>
    <form action="login" method="post">
        name: <input type="text" name="userName"><br/>
        password<input type="password" name="userPassword">
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
</body>
```

And this is my servlet:

```
package practicea;

public class OnServletLogin extends HttpServlet{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res )
        throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        String user = req.getParameter("userName");
        String pass = req.getParameter("userPassword");

        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        if(user.equals("h") && pass.equals("2")) {
            pw.println("Success");
        } else {
            pw.println("fail");
        }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

And here is my web.xml so that I can perform the mapping

```
<display-name>practicea</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>practicea.OnServletLogin</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This is my original JSP code:

```
String action = request.getParameter("login"):
String username = request.getParameter("userName");
String password = request.getParameter("userPassword");

if(action.equals("login") {
    if(username.equals("h") && password.equals("2") {
         out.print("success");        
    } else {
         out.print("fail");
    }
}

<body>  .... </body>
```

It works fine and I decided let try servlet. And ... compile errors ...

Project Structure:

```
practicea
:
:....src
:     :..practicea
:            :... OnServletLogin.java
:
:....WebContent
      :..Home.jsp
      :..WEB-INF
         :..web.xml
```

Comment: Is your `OnServletLogin.class` on the tomcat classpath?

Comment: Do I need to set the servlet on tomcat classpath if I am using eclipse running on ubuntu? If I am only implement the login code in JSP file alone (without servlet), it deploys and runs perfectly.

Comment: where is your OnServletLogin.class relative to your jsp?

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` basically some path problem post the project structure

Comment: updated the project structure. I tried to reinstalled tomcat according to several results found by google search but none of them work.

Comment: The error is due to some path problem i.e the pth in web.xml may not be correct. are you having your servlet package inside src? try removing method=post and changing the method name to service instead of dopost.

Comment: If your project structure is the structure in Tomcat itself, the issue is that you only have `OnServletLogin.java` and no `OnServletLogin.class` and that its not in the right spot. Should be under `web-inf\classes\your-package-name\`. If this is your Eclipse structure, then I don't know.

Comment: @user3819470 did you tried without the `/`, ie /login to login..?? Did you tried to rebuild the project. Its a common when the project wont deploy.